# overflow icon doesnt appear in some android version (4.1.2)

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-styles

the overflow icon in the menu bar does not appear in some android versions like 4.1.2 but works fine in android versions 5.0,6.0.....
Also I want to make clicking on the share item should generate a list over there like in gallery apps...

Here's the code:

**first.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aboutusActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.share) {
//sharing implementation here
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "आरती गणपतीची");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "download kara from google.com/arti-sangrah");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".first">

<item android:id="@+id/action_about" android:title="About Us"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"/>
<item android:id="@+id/share" android:title="Share"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"/>
</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="OverFlowStyle"    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/dot</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowStyle</item>
    <item   name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlowStyle</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For first use `always` instead of `never` ,here  `app:showAsAction="always"` or you can use `ifRoom`.
2. for second you just need to create a intent with `ACTION_SEND` and i guess it  already there so if you want to do something else try this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html)

Comment: Using always/ifRoom in app:showAsAction causes separate items in the action bar....I want the items to be shown from the overflow icon...

Comment: if you are asking for 3 dot icon in action bar then it depend upon android and device structure . some have menu button so they don't have menu overflow icon.